# Liquibase update for database over secured connection

Tags: liquibase, ojdbc, oracle19c

We are using liquibase maven plugin to execute changelogs in database. We have been told to use connection over TLS. Our services are successfully connecting to database using Java Keystore and Trust Store. But we are facing issue while executing liquibase over CLI. Can you please help how to execute liquibase over CLI for database connection over TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase does not have a setting to configure the TLS. It is something that ins typically on figured in Oracle (in sqlnet.ora or on the client side using security.java)

If you need to set up Oracle wallet which is sometimes the case with using TLS, you can refer to this documentation: https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/oracle-atp-db.html